# 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

Tags: skywalking

skywalking-php-sdk安装中make提示如下：
/root/skywalking-5.0.1/src/sky_core_log.c:66:5: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

Comment: I'd love to have the conversation with you in Chinese, unfortunately, it's not allowed on StackOverflow. It is an English forum.

Comment: OK,we can communicate in English, thank you

Comment: ... What I tried to point out is that only presenting the error message is vague, not to mention 95% of the people can't even read it. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?